# JavaFX 2.2 : buttons goes out of the Vbox layout when shrinking the stage

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I'm building a sample CRUD application with javafx, this is my FXML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<BorderPane fx:id="root" depthTest="ENABLE"  maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity"
                        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="org.tarrsalah.persona.gui.MainViewPresenter">

    <center>
        <TableView fx:id="table" minHeight="500.0" minWidth="600.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="name" fx:id="name" />
                <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="last name" fx:id="lastname" />
            </columns>
            <BorderPane.margin>
                <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
            </BorderPane.margin>
        </TableView>
    </center>

    <right>
        <VBox VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS" fillWidth="true"   spacing="10.0" BorderPane.alignment="TOP_LEFT" minWidth="200" >
            <children >
                <Button fx:id="newP"  prefWidth="100.0" minWidth="80"  text="New" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
                <Button fx:id="alter"  prefWidth="100.0" minWidth="80" text="Alter" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
                <Button fx:id="remove" prefWidth="100.0" minWidth="80" text="remove" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
            </children>
            <padding>
                <Insets left="20.0" right="20.0" top="10.0" />
            </padding>      
        </VBox>
    </right>
</BorderPane>
```

when  trying to resize the stage all the buttons goes out of Vbox layout as you can see

[image: before shrinkin]
[image: after shrinking]

how can I preserve Vbox pane from shrinking ?

Comment: Did you tried to remove the minWidth="600.0" on the TableView ?

Comment: No I didn't, thanks @gontard

Comment: Removing the minWith rsolved your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is caused by the minimum width contraint on the TableView.

```
<TableView fx:id="table" minHeight="500.0" minWidth="600.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0">
```

You should remove the attribute `minWidth="600.0"` to allows the `TableView` to reduce its width below 600px.